# iPhone 5 gyroscope behaving badly

Tags: ios, iphone-5, gyroscope

I am in the process of developing an iPhone app that uses the devices X and Y CMMotionManager orientation.

When I've been testing my app on ipod touch's and iPads I've had no problems when I place the device on a level surface the X and Y attitude variables equal roughly 0.

BUT

When I tested it on an iPhone 5 the Y variable was equal to around -6 and the X about 6 on the same level surface!!

Is this an ios bug? or something wrong with my code?

Any help with this would greatly appreciated.

This is my code btw:

```
    motion = gyroscopeManager.deviceMotion;
  NSString *x = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 180 * motion.gravity.x / M_PI];
 NSString *y = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 180 * motion.gravity.y / M_PI];
```

Comment: Do they all have the same version of iOS installed?

Comment: Yes, also I tested the app on three different iPhone 5's and all of them did the same thing

Comment: I only have access to one device but experienced some similar issues as well s. [Drifting yaw angle after moving fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613239/drifting-yaw-angle-after-moving-fast). I filed a bug report. They tried to close it, I reopened it, now it's one of those zombies in the database. Surprisingly I got my problems were reduced when switching from gyro to gravity based control

Comment: Hmm ok, thanks for that, I might try it in ios 7 beta see if its been fixed

Comment: Ok app behaves exactly the same as before on ios 7 pre-release :(

Comment: If you can confirm this with a demo project like [MotionGraphs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MotionGraphs/Introduction/Intro.html) it would be worth a bug report.

Comment: Ok i've done some testing. I cannot replicate the problem on MotionGraphs app, Thank you @Kay for suggesting that. I have the found that the problem is temperamental. Sometimes the app (my app) will display an accurate reading while other times it will do the -6 thing. Grrr!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! in another section of my code I had included a method that checked the devices acceleration, when I removed this method the gyroscope behaved normally!